# Why didn't Daenerys take help from Daario Naharis?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As observed in S8E4, Daenerys needs all the people she can get to fight Cersei. Why didn't she ask Dario Naharis and second sons to join the war?

Comment: +1 and Yara and her iron fleet too, and probably the south (they hate the Lannisters)

Comment: @Anu7 I think it's stated, or at least implied, that the ships they use to get to Dragonstone are Yara's, it's just we don't see Yara.

Comment: Yara was at the iron islands, so not in a position to (quickly) help.

Comment: The beacons didn't work........

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot oh !!! those are Yara's ships ? I did not know that. But yes good to know.

Comment: On a side note, I'd say Daario Naharis is probably the best strategist Dany has, surely better than Tyrion or Jon, who made lots and lots of blunders recently. He was the one who correctly understood that the Unsullied were ineffective against the Sons of the Harpy, and the Second Sons would have done a better job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are on the other side of the world. Reaching them with the message and then waiting for them to sail to Westeros is not something Daenerys would be willing to wait for. Remember that she refused to give her troops even a few days rest after the Battle for Winterfell before marching on King's Landing.

Her (dubious) reasoning for this was that her army would be getting weaker, while Cersei's grows stronger by the day.

Comment: Yup. After the battle of Winterfell, she controls the iron islands (taken to Cersei's side), Dorne, and part of Stormlands thanks to Gendry, while Cersei needs to pay the golden company every day. Time is definitely helping Cersei...

Comment: She has no real control over the Stormlands.  The only people that might recognize her authority to appoint him its lord were already right there.  And right there wasn't the Stormlands.  It was little more than a ceremonial gesture, which would only bear fruit well into the future.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy which is relevant... why?

Answer (score 3):

Dany was insulted and looked ready to start burning people when it was suggested that they try to rest from the battle of Winterfell.

When Tyrion and others arrive at the camp outside King's Landing on the night before battle he tells Jon and the others that Dany wants the attack to begin "immediately." Glances were exchanged and Jon said they would attack the following morning.  It won't surprise me if Dany brings up that delay in ep 6 next week.

With that level of urgency from Dany, there is simply no way that she was going to sit around waiting to see if the Second Sons could make it across the sea from Essos without being sunk by Euron's fleet.

And beyond the issues of time and logistics, if Dany wanted to keep having sex with Daario then she would have brought him with her in the first place.  She left him behind because he was not suitable as a queen's consort and nothing about that has changed.  Daario is probably the last person she would call to her side.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget he was essentially appointed as the head of law enforcement on her departure.  She tasked him with keeping the peace and keeping Mereen from reverting to slavery or just generally crumbling into chaos. Removing him would basically mean accepting that Mereen may crumble and her changes undone.

Also, they probably couldn't fit his abs into the budget.